# Vim ma`a goes to next line

Tags: vim

I'm having a problem with markers in vim. I wrote the following shortcut:

```
noremap <Leader>i magg=G`a<CR>
```

The problem is that when I'm using it the cursor jumps to the next line, and sometimes also a few characters on the left. Why is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you told it to by adding <CR> at the end.

Comment: Woops, sorry about that :)